# Embedding of Schwartz space into $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Tags: real-analysis, schwartz-space

I want to show that the embedding of Schwartz space into $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the standard norm of each space.

I don't quite see how to work with the topologies. Any theorems that I can make use of here?

Comment: Norm, metric, or multinorm?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy Schwartz space the one over https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space here, and $C^\infty$ the $\sup_{x\in K\text{ compact}}|\frac{\partial^\alpha}{\partial x^{\alpha}}f|$ one.